# Passing parameters from Activity.onCreate into other methods

Tags: java, android

I am currently learning Java and am a rookie at Android. Below is my onCreate method, and towards the end of it I have two `EditText` fields, `passT` (Plain text) and `keyT` (encryption key). I want to pass these two as parameters into my encryption method (also below) and retreive the result and set the value in the cipher `EditText`.

I'd like to have the value set to an email address that the user will input (`emailT`, currently no `EditText` field set for it).

```
public class ScreenNext extends Activity {

    int key = 0;
    static char ch;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_next)

        EditText emailT;//Import  EditTexts (Key and Email)  
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);//Import button1 (Send)
        final EditText passT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTogg);//passT variable for Password Text for EditText field
        final EditText keyT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKey);
        final EditText passT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTogg);//passT variable for Password Text for EditText field

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String keyText = keyT.getText().toString();
                String passText = passT.getText().toString();
            }

        });

    }//End onCreate
    ...
}
```

My Encryption method (others included in case they need to be observed for my solution):

```
public static String message(String choice, String subKey, String message) {
    int Option = Integer.parseInt(choice);//Must pareseInt
    int key = Integer.parseInt(subKey);
    message = message.toLowerCase();

    //If the key is 26, prompt the user to change the key

    if (key % 26 == 0) {

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can't use a modulus of 26 as a key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    ScreenNext subcipher_1 = null;
    String CipherTxt = subcipher_1.encrypt(message, key);
    return CipherTxt;
}

// Message prompt method finished, now we create the method that has the
// encrypting algorithms

public static String encrypt(String Txt, int key) {

    //local var cipherText of type string is init empty
    String CipherTxt = "";//May be able to remove this'un 
    String cText="";
    //enhanced for loop 
    // start at 0, go until "as long as input text" 
    for (int i = 0; i < Txt.length(); i++) {
        //get a char from the string at index i (start at 0 work through to end of string)
        // and store in local var extractedChar for type char
        char extractedChar = Txt.charAt(i);
        /* enhanced for loop 
         * start at 0, go until end of user entered cipherKeyValue
         * either set to lowercase a or add one to the char
         * uses the checkifz method
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < key; j++) {
            ScreenNext subcipher_1 = null;
            if (subcipher_1.checkIfZ(extractedChar) == true) {
                extractedChar = 'a';
            } else {
                extractedChar++;
            }
            CipherTxt= new StringBuilder().append(extractedChar).toString();
        }
        //add extracted char to builder object
        //change object builder to string and assing to cipherText of type String
        //create new object builder from StringBuilder class
        cText = cText.concat(CipherTxt);
    }
    //Pass the cipherText value out of the method to whom ever called it

    return cText;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Declare the variables at class level

```
public class ScreenNext extends Activity {

    int key = 0;
    static char ch;
    String keyText = null;
    String passText = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ....
        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                keyText = keyT.getText().toString();
                passText = passT.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Aaarrrrgggghhhhh.  What is this disease inflicting SO? My eyes are burning.  My brain is turning to slush and leaking out through my nostrils.  The horned devils of the Caspian sea are poking me with live eels.  My dog is actually a werewolf.  Anyone who types the word "global" when referring to variables should be forced to take a test on basic programming.  These are NOT global.  Globals, by definition, have scope and lifetime equal to the application.  These are *class fields* or *class level variables*.  They are NOT globals. They are the work of the devil and should be burned at the stake

Comment: OK, so anyone reading the above and questioning my sanity should know that @Dennis kindly edited his answer...

Comment: Thanks allot for that. Have you looked at my encryption methods, though? I currently don't have any reference of the keyText and passText variables; I have others as the code was originally written in a Java IDE.

How should I go about implementing these new variables to my encryption?

Comment: When you call the method, use these variables as parameters: `encrypt(passText, keyText);`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, much obliged!